# Using setInterval with d3js to update values

Tags: d3.js

I'm not really sure if this question is a complete mess. Please, if somebody can tell me something it will be really appreciated.

I'm trying to update an existing arc being drawn with d3js:

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(0)
    .innerRadius(70)
    .outerRadius(100);

setInterval(function(){ change(); },3000);

function change() {
    var x = d3.selectAll("some_entity")
          .data(data)
          .attr("d", arc.endAngle(twoPi * 0.7) )
          .attr("class", function(d) { return d.some_field });
}
```

This code works exactly as expected. "Some_entities" are selected, the data is set, 70% of the arc is drawn and the class attribute is filled with the corresponding data. If I change the "d" attribute to be drawn based on data like:

```
function change() {
    var x = d3.selectAll("some_entity")
          .data(data)
          .attr("d", function(d) { return arc.endAngle(twoPi * d.progress); } )
          .attr("class", function(d) { return d.some_field });
}
```

something weird happens. This error is thrown:

```
Error: Problem parsing d="function n(){var n=t.apply(this,arguments),i=e.apply(this,arguments),o=r.apply(this,arguments)+ys,a=u.apply(this,arguments)+ys,c=(o>a&&(c=o,o=a,a=c),a-o),s=Sa>c?"0":"1",l=Math.cos(o),...
```

It is like if the arc function wasn't being evaluated at all!. The body of the function is returned (or something like that). I don't know if it's due to the context of the function. I've tried different approaches, like trying to store the arc in a more global context or to recreate the object inside, but nothing works.

If I evaluate the function it actually returns an arc (the corresponding svg path). But I can't understand why it is behaving different. Am I calling to different objects?

Comment: A jsbin/jsfiddle would be nice so that others can experiment easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely you'll see that the non-working call is in a function whereas the working call isn't:

```
.attr("d", arc.endAngle(twoPi * 0.7) )  // working
.attr("d", function(d) { return arc.endAngle(twoPi * d.progress); } )  // not working
```

If you don't declare a function explicitly, Javascript passes through the arguments. So to make it work with an explicit function, you need to pass the argument through explicitly:

```
.attr("d", function(d) { return arc.endAngle(twoPi * d.progress)(d); } )
```

That's what the error message you're getting is telling you -- you are indeed returning an unevaluated function, which is the return value of `arc.endAngle()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lars. Now I see it :)